# Should the output of Apriori algorithm be a one to one relationship

Tags: python, python-3.x, apriori

I am currently following this guide:

https://stackabuse.com/association-rule-mining-via-apriori-algorithm-in-python/

as an output all of the rules are of the form:

```
light cream ----> chicken
```

is this correct, should the output always be a one to one relationship in the apriori algorithm, or can we (or should) we have something like

```
{light cream, chocolate} -----> strawberries
```

Answer (score 0):

From the tutorial in reference:

> ...Lift can be calculated for item 1 and item 2, item 1 and item 3,
>   item 1 and item 4...

So, yes, several items can have a transaction defined on the same item;

Actually, the way you are describing it:

```
{light cream, chocolate} -----> strawberries
```

is a bit of syntactic sugar over this:

```
light cream -----> strawberries
chocolate   -----> strawberries
```

If you want to associate two items to create a transaction, you probably want to create a new one like

```
light cream and chocolate -----> strawberries
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to Reblochon's answer, it doesn't hurt to know that these association rules are different from each other:

- light cream -----> strawberries
- chocolate   -----> strawberries
- {light cream, chocolate} -----> strawberries

Each of these rules can have a confidence score different from the other two. All permutations of items (e.g. 6 permutations for a frequent item-set of size 3) should be considered when generating the association rules and filtering them according to the confidence scores.